# Mongoid Syntax Questions

Tags: mongoid

1) Finding by instance object

Assuming I have the instance object called @topic. I want to retrieve the answers for this given topic. I was thinking I should be able to pass in :topics=>@topic, but i had to do the very ugly query below.

```
  @answers = Answers.where(:topic_ids => {"$in" => [@topic.id]})
```

2) Getting the string representation of the id. I have a custom function (shown below). But shouldn't this be a very common requirement?

```
  def sid
    return id.to_s
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your associations are set up correctly, you should be able to do:

```
@topic.answers
```

It sounds like the above is what you are looking for. Make sure you have set up your associations correctly. Mongoid is very forgiving when defining associations, so it can seem that they are set up right when there is in fact a problem like mismatched names in `references_many` and `referenced_in`.

If there's a good reason why the above doesn't work and you have to use a query, you can use this simple query:

```
@answers = Answer.where(:topic_ids => @topic.id)
```

This will match any `Answer` record whose topic_ids include the supplied ID. The syntax is the same for array fields as for single-value fields like `Answer.where(:title => 'Foo')`. MongoDB will interpret the query differently depending on whether the field is an array (check if supplied value is in the array) or a single value (check if the supplied value is a match).

Here's a little more info on how MongoDB handles array queries:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray

Comment: hmmm, the example you gave does not seem to work - am i doing anything wrong?
@answers = @user.answers.where(:topic_ids.in => @topic.id)

Comment: Sorry, I led you down the wrong path. You shouldn't use the `$in` operator (or the `.in` Mongoid Symbol extension) for this type of query. Please see the updated answer.